# Font Awesome is loaded but not working

Tags: fonts, font-face, font-awesome

Why is [Font Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/) not working on this [site](http://reggi.myshopify.com/)? At the bottom of the page there are three icons and the middle library should be font awesome.

I've got three font icon libraries loading and there are no asset errors occurring, each font occupies a different set of classes, so I can't imagine any css conflicts.

I know this is a crappy post, but I'm super desperate.

Comment: Oh, come on!!! Really a negative vote...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly, I think it has something to do with your "src" attribute. BEFORE I downloaded and installed FA, and it worked ok in FF, but the checkmark icon in Safari failed. After the download/install locally, all is well.

Your current "src" attribute:

```
//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0163/0698/t/13/assets/fontawesome-webfont.woff?16685
```

I've never used the cdn on shopify.com, but from where I sit, I'm not ruling it out as a possible culprit to your predicament -- especially, since you're domain doesn't live on shopify.com.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH. I am forever in you debt! I feel like you just saved jar-jar binks from those droids or alternatively gave dobby a sock!

Comment: Glad to help. Upvoted your question (vs your comment) as a Thanks for giving me my first laugh this morning. Go Dobby!